# Single line bash command to rename all files with name A to name B

Tags: bash, rename, subdirectory

Given the file and folder structure:

```
test
├── a
│   └── hans.x
├── b
│   └── hans.x
└── c
    └── hans.x
```

I would like to **use a single line bash command to rename all files "hans.x" to "peter.x".**

Desired Result:

```
test
├── a
│   └── peter.x
├── b
│   └── peter.x
└── c
    └── peter.x
```

I have looked at many solutions on SO and found lots of solutions that show how to rename the file "peter.x" to "peter.x_somethingmore", but never the above scenario.

I have tried the following:

```
find . -type f -name 'hans.x' -print0 | xargs --null -I{} mv {} "$(dirname "{}")"peter.x
```

But unfortunately, that results in the following execution:

```
mv ./test/a/hans.x .peter.x
mv ./test/c/hans.x .peter.x
mv ./test/b/hans.x .peter.x
```

Comment: have you considered using a script (e.g. python) for this task?  Bash has pretty gnarly syntax

Comment: @anon01 I have considered python, but I prefer to use built in bash commands to achieve such a simple task, rather than write a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` is expanded before `xargs` is executed. You want to run it all inside a subshell created when parsing the line:

```
   ... | xargs -0n1 sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(dirname "$1")"/hans.y' _
```

Comment: It almost is as if my 'dirname' command was not executed properly: I tried this replacing mv with echo.    find -type f -name 'hans.x' -print0 | xargs -0n1 sh -c 'echo ""$1" "$(dirname "$1")"/hans.y"'   
The output was as follows:
 ./hans.y
 ./hans.y
 ./hans.y

Comment: There's a `_` on the end - it's important. The syntax is `sh -c <script> <$0> <$1> ...` the `_` is assigned to `$0`. You may remove it and use `$0` in the script or have it and use `$1`.

Comment: Wow. That did it. What does that "_" do?

Comment: Edited comment above. For more information see [man sh](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sh.1p.html) and inspect `-c` option.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `find`, you could use [`-execdir`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dexecdir):

```sh
find -type f -name 'hans.x' -execdir mv {} peter.x \;
```

Comment: This leads to the following output for me: The relative path ‘~/bin’ is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH

Comment: @avgJoe That's odd, do you have the `~` hardcoded in your `PATH`?

Comment: I have '~/bin' in my path

Comment: @avgJoe Make that wherever you set your `PATH` (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or similar), the tilde isn't quoted. If it is quoted, it'll be added to your `PATH` literally (and results in the message you see); when unquoted, it expands to the absolute path of `$HOME/bin` and you don't see that error message.